# How the token-size can be greater than 1 in the Metaplex Auction House CLI for sell

Tags: javascript, typescript, command-line-interface, solana, metaplex

Working with the Metaplex Auction House CLI (ah-cli) latest version (commit 472973f2437ecd9cd0e730254ecdbd1e8fbbd953 from May 27 12:54:11 2022) is only letting have the **--token-size 1** and do not let create **auction sell** with values greater than 1, even for a Master Edition minted with 10 copies.

```
ts-node src/auction-house-cli.ts sell -k ~/.config/solana/myId.json -ah GvH97dakw2FsJE8RHndfTUuMZKcSJX6cjvn66Ax9hEJ7 -b 2.7 -m 9wqzeSn7KHR8ur6wxBTAA9e9Ah8C2rew5L5N2QFmPe78 -t 3
```

This is the error being returned:

```
/Users/bahia/solana/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/transactions.ts:143
            throw new Error(
                  ^
Error: Transaction failed: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InvalidTokenAmount. Error Number: 6015. Error Message: Invalid token amount.
    at sendSignedTransaction (/Users/bahia/solana/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/transactions.ts:143:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async sendTransactionWithRetryWithKeypair (/Users/bahia/solana/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/transactions.ts:66:26)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/bahia/solana/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/auction-house-cli.ts:330:5)
```

Anyone has any idea on how to have --token-size greater than 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a non-fungible token, its not possible to set `--token-size` > 1 due to nature of NFTs: there can not be more than 1 token with the same `mint_address`.

The use-case for `--token-size` > 1 is SPL-tokens / fungible assets, where more than 1 tokens can have the same `mint_address`.

In the case of Master Editions with > 1 copies, they are still non-fungible assets and the copies don't have the same `mint_address`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

I totally understand your point that for an NFT each `mint_address` must be unique, however in this case there is the option `--token-size` ... and if `token-size` must be one, what would be the reason to exist such option?

Comment: @Nayib --token-size need not be one and that is what I have explained in my answer. It can be > 1 for SPL-tokens.